# Android Eclipse Edit String of values directory in Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, edit

I want to edit a string of the `/values/` directory from the Java activity file.

It should be like that:

```
String new_value = "hello";
R.string.string_name = new_value;
new_value = "bye";
R.string.string_name = new_value;
```

But it doesn't work.

It's because I want to edit the string and then start a new activity and then open the string. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`R.string.string_name` Is an `Integer`. it cannot be equal to an string!

`R.string.string_name` maps to an address actually using a file that is generated by the SDK everytime you make a change to them. So it's not possible.

BTW I can't understand why you want to do it when you can just pass strings with the intent. like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("string1", new_value);
startActivity(intent);
```

and then read the value from the new activity like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String new_value = intent.getStringExtra("string1");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I searched for something like that. Now it works!!

In Visual Basic, you can start Subs like that:

my_vb_sub("string1")

But I didn't find a way to do that in Java/Android.

Yes, now it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on some research i did on SO. [How to change R.string.some_variable at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933388/how-to-change-r-string-some-variable-at-run-time) It seems that what your trying to do is not possible. R is generated at development time by the SDK tools.

Answer (score 0):

A string resource provides text strings for your application with optional text styling and formatting.

You can use either getString(int) or getText(int) to retrieve a string. getText(int) will retain any rich text styling applied to the string.

```
String string = getString(R.string.hello);
```

Anyway, Strings in a xml file should be static. What if you your application has to support different language ?

The solution to your problem is to send an extra value within the Intent you are providing to switch between activities.

If you need a specific String only for a specific Activity, you should create another static String.